# for loop with array ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, for-loop

I have to find a way to check (at the touch of a button) if the text in a textfield is present in an xml file.

I thought that if I load the xml file as an array then I could use a for loop to see if it is the same result as in the array.

are not at all practical for loops, could you explain me how can I write the code for this kind of problem?

I want that if the object is not present in the whole array then show the alert

thanks

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
  {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

cose = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"giovanni",@"giulio",@"ciccio",@"panzo", nil];

 }

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
  {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

  -(IBAction)prova {

for (NSString *myElement in cose) {
    if ([myElement isEqualToString:textfield1.text]) {
        label1.text = textfield1.text;

    }
    else {

        UIAlertView *alertCellulare = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Attenzione!"       message:@"connessione assente" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

        [alertCellulare show];
    }
}

}
```

Comment: what is text1? where do u set it? how are we supposed to know, why your if always fails without those informations?

Comment: I changed it is now clear,
seems coming out of the alert to anything that is different from the word that I have written until it finds

Comment: that is exactly what you coded. what did u expect?

Comment: if I write this code when I enter a name in this array in textfield1, is seen in label1, but also leaves the alert, and instead should not .. how to do?

Comment: btw: 1) you are using the xcode-tag wrong. just if a question is about the editor xcode, you should add it. 2) although you only post very few lines of code, it is annoying to read if for the lack of proper indentation.

Comment: ok sorry anyway you can help me?

Comment: ok i try to explain better

Comment: I want that if the object is not present in the whole array then show the alert

Comment: i writed it in question...

Comment: have to find a way to check (at the touch of a button) if the text in a textfield is present in an xml file.

I thought that if I load the xml file as an array then I could use a for loop to see if it is the same result as in the array.

are not at all practical for loops, could you explain me how can I write the code for this kind of problem?

thanks

thanks Eljay, I tried to write this code and it works, but in else I put an alert, and in any case I get the alert ... how could I do?

I want that if the object is not present in the whole array then show the alert

Comment: at the end there is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With fast-enumeration:

```
-(IBAction)prova 
{
    BOOL present = NO;
    for (NSString *myElement in cose) {
        if ([myElement isEqualToString:textfield1.text]) {
            label1.text = textfield1.text;
            present = YES;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!present){
        UIAlertView *alertCellulare = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Attenzione!"       message:@"connessione assente" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alertCellulare show];
    }
}
```

---

with block based enumeration

```
-(IBAction)prova 
{
    __block BOOL present = NO;
    [cose enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *name, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop){

        if ([name isEqualToString:textfield1.text]) {
            label1.text = textfield1.text;
            present = YES;
            *stop = YES;
        }

     }];

    if (!present){
        UIAlertView *alertCellulare = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Attenzione!"       message:@"connessione assente" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alertCellulare show];
    }
}
```

Comment: if I write this code tells me that 'present' is not declared

Comment: thank you very much viking the second code is perfect! thank you!

Comment: both are semantical identical. the second one should be a bit faster.

Comment: +1 for throwing block based enumeration in there.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a For-In loop (fast enumeration)?

Something like this:

```
for (NSString *myElement in myArray) {
    if ([myElement isEqualToString:myTextField.text]) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```